# Application of the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion

Tags: combinatorics

This is problem 25 from chapter 2, Stanley’s Enumerative Combinatorics Volume 1.

> $$ \begin{align}
>        \mbox{(a) } &\text{ [2]* Let $ f_i(m, n) $ be the number of $ m \times n $ matrices of $ 0 $'s and $ 1 $'s with at least }
>   \\   &\text{ one $ 1 $ in every row and column, and with a total of $ i $ $ 1 $'s. Use the Principle of }
>   \\   &\text{ Inclusion-Exclusion to show that }
>      \end{align}
>   $$
>
> $$ \sum_i f_i(m, n)t^i = \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} ((1 + t)^{n - k} - 1)^m \text{.} \qquad \qquad \mbox{(2.54)}$$

I’m quite confused here because I don’t know how to compare this to the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion. Should I first expand the RHS to get the coefficient of $t^i$?
I was trying to get something like $$f_{=}(\phi)=\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{y\subset\{1,...,n\},|y|=k}(-1)^k f_{\geq}(y).$$But that just doesn’t make sense here.

Any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: Don't expand anything; that would give you a neat proof but not the one using Inclusion-Exclusion. Instead, count these matrices by first counting all $m\times n$-matrices of $0$'s and $1$'s with at least one $1$ in each row and a **given** number $k$ of $1$-less columns. (Or maybe switch rows and columns.)

Comment: What do you mean by “... and a given number $k$ of $1$-less columns”?

Comment: Actually, a given $k$-element set of $1$-less columns. You fix $k$ distinct elements of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$ and **require** that the corresponding $k$ columns of your matrix are all-$0$s.

Comment: Thank you! I have figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I thought about this problem:

1. $\binom{n}{k}$ represents choosing $k$ things from a set of $n$ things. There's only one set of $n$ things in the picture, so that must mean choosing $k$ columns of the matrix.
2. $(1 + t)^{n - k}$ is the generating function for subsets of $n - k$.
3. Presumably the $n - k$ are the columns not chosen in step 1.
4. $(1 + t)^{n - k} - 1$ is the generating function for non-empty subsets of $n - k$.
5. $((1 + t)^{n - k} - 1)^m$ is the generating function for $m$ (ordered) non-empty subsets of $n - k$.
6. Specifically $[t^i]((1 + t)^{n - k} - 1)^m$ counts the number of tuples $(A_1,\dots,A_m)$ where each $A_l$ is a non-empty subset of size $n - k$ and $|A_1| + \dots + |A_m| = i$.

Now see if you can put this all together into a proof. (Hint: what is $A_l$ in the matrices enumerated on the left hand side?)